# StringBuilder split the easy way

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

i'm parsing an input `String string` as follows:

```
String temp [] = string.split(" ");
```

and from here on, working all the rest of it on 
`StringBuilder` variables.
The input sequence `string` can be long. The individual tokens parsed out-- the ones "residing" in `temp[]` won't come up later in the application when the method returns. so, I have no advantage in keeping them as `String` types and having them interned. I only have speed the disadvantage.

Is there an easy way to do this splitting on `StringBuilder`? `StringBuilder` has no such method on it.

i can do a manual split-- search `string` for the occurrences of whitespaces and put the sequence of other chars in between consecutive 
whitespaces on a `StringBuilder` variable.

is there a better way of doing this?

TIA.

//=============================

EDIT:

so - if `string` is "apples oranges bananas",

```
String temp [] = string.split(" ");
```

is generating an array of 3,  "apples", "oranges" and "bananas" are sitting in each of these 3 cells. by this, "apples", "oranges" and "bananas" each are being interned. i'm looking to get around this going-into-the-pool-and seeing-whether-"apples"-is-there process for speed concerns.

Comment: You do not need to use any type of arrays?

Comment: did yo try this List<String> temp = Arrays.asList(string.split(" "));

Comment: This sounds like premature optimization. Have you identified that the simplest solution (using the string array) is too slow?

Comment: @AhmadAl-Kurdi I don't think List<String> would give me any advantage on this.

Comment: if you look for optimization I think you can use simple map and reduce in case you have redudant data

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern.compile(" ").split(myStringBuilder)
```

will do the job.  [`Pattern.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence)) accepts an arbitrary `CharSequence`.

Comment: it's still returning a String[]. i'm looking to avoid String[] so that each of those String-s in the array cells won't be interened.

Comment: @Roam why would it be interned?

Comment: @Roam strings aren't automatically interned.  Only `String` _literals_, and `String`s where `intern()` is called explicitly, are interned.